# Oracle analyse query performance

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm analysing the performance of a query.
The method I'm currently using is the below:

```
SELECT
    dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'sql_id', type => 'HTML')
FROM
    dual;
```

With this, I create a html file which gets updated with the query execution. I am able to see there the current status of the execution. However, this might not the best way to do it since the network traffic could be quite heavy (generating the html). However, I can't go with the autotrace option on poor performing queries since it takes forever.

What would be the best way to monitor this kind of poor performing queries?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to monitor?  Are you trying to see when the query is likely to finish, you can probably use `v$session_longops`.  If you are trying to see what the query plan is or get information on the performance of prior executions or something else, there are different options.

Comment: I'm trying to monitor the performance (actual rows fetched, IOs, memory...) of a query without having to wait until the end of it.

Comment: Has it run previously so that you can look at historical performance?  You can see some information in `v$session_longops` for most long running queries but probably not that level of detail.  What exactly is the concern with the network traffic in getting the `dbms_sqltune` report?  Unless you have a severely constrained pipe, I'd expect the network traffic to deliver a report to be pretty trivial on a reasonably busy database.

Comment: Ok, so if that's the case, I will just stick with the bdms_sqltune report. I thought the network traffic could significantly distort the results. This is an open question to double check if any better ways of doing this are available out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `type => 'text'` format to generate a SQL Monitoring Report that is smaller than the HTML version but contains the same data.

In my testing, the HTML format is 8.5 times larger than the text format. However, the HTML file was still only 175 kilobytes, which isn't likely to cause performance issues on most systems. But I still recommend using the text file anyway. The text output is easier to post and share, easier to compare using diff programs, and easier to understand (because for tricky plans you need to line up the operations exactly, which is easier to do in a text editor counting spaces than eyeballing a large HTML file.)

For example, the below never-ending query generates the below text and HTML output.

```
select count(*) from dba_objects, dba_objects, dba_objects;
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => '7jf8pjk8cbnxn', type => 'text') from dual;
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => '7jf8pjk8cbnxn', type => 'HTML') from dual;
```

#### Text

```
SQL Monitoring Report

SQL Text
------------------------------
select count(*) from dba_objects, dba_objects, dba_objects

Global Information
------------------------------
 Status              :  EXECUTING                   
 Instance ID         :  1                           
 Session             :  JHELLER (1836:42702)        
 SQL ID              :  7jf8pjk8cbnxn               
 SQL Execution ID    :  16777216                    
 Execution Started   :  04/01/2021 22:36:33         
 First Refresh Time  :  04/01/2021 22:36:37         
 Last Refresh Time   :  04/01/2021 22:39:25         
 Duration            :  174s                        
 Module/Action       :  PL/SQL Developer/SQL Window 
 Service             :  orclpdb                     
 Program             :  plsqldev.exe                

Global Stats
===================================================================
| Elapsed |   Cpu   |    IO    |  Other   | Buffer | Read | Read  |
| Time(s) | Time(s) | Waits(s) | Waits(s) |  Gets  | Reqs | Bytes |
===================================================================
|     171 |     171 |     0.40 |     0.09 |  36158 |  652 |  12MB |
===================================================================

SQL Plan Monitoring Details (Plan Hash Value=3121580586)
=======================================================================================================================================================================================
| Id    |                  Operation                   |       Name        |  Rows   | Cost |   Time    | Start  | Execs |   Rows   | Read | Read  | Mem | Activity | Activity Detail |
|       |                                              |                   | (Estim) |      | Active(s) | Active |       | (Actual) | Reqs | Bytes |     |   (%)    |   (# samples)   |
=======================================================================================================================================================================================
|     0 | SELECT STATEMENT                             |                   |         |      |       115 |     +4 |     1 |        0 |      |       |   . |          |                 |
|     1 |   SORT AGGREGATE                             |                   |       1 |      |       157 |     +4 |     1 |        0 |      |       |   . |     4.68 | Cpu (8)         |
|  -> 2 |    MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                      |                   |    302T | 530T |       169 |     +4 |     1 |       4G |      |       |   . |          |                 |
|  -> 3 |     MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                     |                   |      5G |   8G |       169 |     +4 |     1 |    85749 |      |       |   . |          |                 |
...
```

#### HTML

[image]

#### Active and V$SESSION_LONGOPS

You might also want to consider using the ACTIVE format, with the parameter `type => 'active'`. Those reports contain information not in either the text or HTML formats, such as parallel active sessions, bloom filter details, and probably other features I'm not aware of. (I'm not including a screenshot because those reports are kind of like the HTML reports but are much more interactive.)

The ACTIVE report is an HTML file with a huge binary CDATA that is interpreted by a player that is retrieved from oracle.com. The binary is the same size as the text version, but downloading the player is a showstopper in most environments. In early versions, the file is run in Flash, which doesn't work anymore in most browsers. Since around 19c, the player is now a JavaScript file, but there are still some difficulties with viewing a report that has to download external dependencies.

Whichever format you go with, I think you've made a good choice for monitoring SQL statements. Most people use V$SESSION_LONGOPS, but that view only shows a small amount of data compared to the monitoring reports, and the content can be misleading. Why settle for looking at the cryptic details of one operation when you can view a well-formatted report for all the operations?

Comment: Thanks! How could I generate an Active format report?

Comment: @JaviTorre Use `type => 'active'`.